# Whether it is possible to draw the color emoji using GDI C#?

Tags: c#, colors, draw, emoji, gdi

I have tried to draw this colored emoji by using the [Graphics.DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Single_System_Single_System_Drawing_StringFormat_) API.

[image: Expected color emoji]

But it has drawn in black & white, without colors, as you can see on the screenshot below:

[image: Output black & white emoji]

I could not find any additional options that may allow the text to be drawn using colored symbols instead of black & white. Is there a way to activate the support of the color in GDI [DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Single_System_Single_System_Drawing_StringFormat_) function, and if yes, how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GDI - Can I use the new Windows 10 Segoe UI Emoji colored font with DrawText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892844/gdi-can-i-use-the-new-windows-10-segoe-ui-emoji-colored-font-with-drawtext)

Comment: Are you using an emoji image file like(png) or Unicode value of emoji?

Comment: zulqadar idrishi - I'm using Unicode value of emoji.